# Phoenix Framework callbacks

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Does the Phoenix Framework employ any types of callback filter such as those found in [Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)? I know it is possible to validate changesets, but I am looking for ways to implement actions such as `before_create`,  `before_save` and `after_commit`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ecto does: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/#!Ecto.Model.Callbacks.html

They are sightly different from the Rails ones: they receive and must return changesets and must be used for data consistency (don't use them to send e-mails and what not).

Comment: The page says that "Warning: Ecto callbacks are deprecated.". This method is probably not recommended anymore

Comment: Yes and they have been completely removed from Ecto 2.0. Here is the blog post explaining some decisions: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/12/ecto-v1-1-released-and-ecto-v2-0-plans/

Comment: Here is another point of view (if you are coming from Rails): http://cloudless.pl/articles/11-model-callbacks-in-phoenix-ecto-and-rails

Answer (score 13):

**From Ecto 2.0, callbacks have been completely removed.**

So how to handle callbacks now?. Here are two ways

For `before_` callbacks you can use [Changeset](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html) itself. One of the reasons callbacks where removed was because *many developers relied on callbacks in many cases where changesets would suffice*. So simply apply the required function to your changeset,

```
def changeset(post, params \\ :empty) do
  post
  |> cast(params, @required_params, @optional_params)
  |> validate_length(:title, min: 3)
  |> validate_length(:metadata, min: 3)
  |> implement_a_before_callback
end

def implement_a_before_callback(changeset)
   #Apply required actions and return Changeset
end
```

Another way, is to group multiple repo operations together using [Ecto.Multi](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html). From the docs

> Ecto.Multi makes it possible to pack operations that should be performed together (in a single database transaction) and gives a way to introspect the queued operations without actually performing them. Each operation is given a name that is unique and will identify its result or will help to identify the place of failure in case it occurs.
>   So whenever you want a group of data related operations to happen at once you could use `Multi`, both `before_` and `after_` callbacks can be substituted here.

An example would be

```
  # In defmodule Service
  def password_reset(account, params) do
    Multi.new
    |> Multi.update(:account, Account.password_reset_changeset(account, params))
    |> Multi.insert(:log, Log.password_reset_changeset(account, params))
    |> Multi.delete_all(:sessions, assoc(account, :sessions))
  end
```

Run it using

```
result = Repo.transaction(Service.password_reset(account, params))
```

You have to remember that you must execute data related queries and not do other tasks like send an email. For that you can simply pattern match on the result and perform appropriate action. Lets sat you wanted to send a mail if the transaction was successful and display some error message if not

```
case result do
  {:ok, %{account: account, log: log, sessions: sessions}} ->
    # Operation was successful, perform actions like sending a mail
  {:error, failed_operation, failed_value, changes_so_far} ->
    # One of the operations failed. Raise error message
end
```

Source:

- http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/12/ecto-v1-1-released-and-ecto-v2-0-plans/
- https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html
- http://cloudless.studio/articles/11-model-callbacks-in-phoenix-ecto-and-rails

Comment: This is the way! Accepted answer is outdated.